# Javafx application - Robot action unable to perform on login screen - Stuck at Launch need to move on testcase loginlogout call when calling from main

Tags: javafx, testfx

Javafx application - Robot action unable to perform on login screen - Stuck at Launch need to move on testcase loginlogout call when calling from main.

I would like to run login logout testcase on javafx application.
I have run the main method.
I am able to launch the application.
And then how to reach to the testcase call.

NOTE: If I run this through Junit this is working fine. But the requirement is to run via Main.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.testfx.api.FxRobot;
import org.testfx.api.FxRobotContext;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.Start;
import io.mosip.registration.config.AppConfig;
import io.mosip.registration.controller.Initialization;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VerticalDirection;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import qa114.pages.DemographicPage;
import qa114.pages.HomePage;
import qa114.pages.LoginPage;
import qa114.pojo.schema.Root;
import qa114.pojo.schema.Schema;
import qa114.runapplication.StartApplication;
import qa114.utility.JsonUtil;
import  qa114.utility.PropertiesUtil;



/***
 * 
 * Login and Logout RegClient
 * Steps Run this using Junit
 * First start method invokes and this will launch Registration Client and through dependency injection
 * 
 * Fxrobot will take control of primary stage and perform keyboard and mouse driven activities.
 *
 */
@ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class)

public class LoginLogoutTest extends Application{

    FxRobot robot;
    Schema schema;
    Root root; 
    Scene scene;
    Node node;
    Boolean flagContinueBtnFileUpload=true;
    Boolean flagContinueBtnBioUpload=true;
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private static Stage applicationPrimaryStage;
    private static String upgradeServer = null;
    private static String tpmRequired = "Y";
    LoginPage loginPage;
    HomePage homePage;
    PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil;
    FxRobotContext context;
    Boolean result=false;
    @FXML
    private WebView webView;


    @Start
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        String[] args=new String[2];
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
            System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
            io.mosip.registration.context.ApplicationContext.getInstance();
            if (args.length > 1) {
                upgradeServer = args[0];
                tpmRequired = args[1];
                io.mosip.registration.context.ApplicationContext.setTPMUsageFlag(args[1]);
            }

            applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

            System.out.println("Automaiton Script - ApplicationContext has taken");

            Initialization initialization=new Initialization();
            initialization.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

            applicationPrimaryStage=primaryStage;
            System.out.println("Title:"+primaryStage.getTitle());

            initialization.start(primaryStage);

            System.out.println("Automaiton Script - ApplicationPrimaryStage has started");


            primaryStage=initialization.getPrimaryStage();


            System.out.println("Automaiton Script - Done with Start invoke");
            context = new FxRobotContext();
            context.setPointPosition(Pos.CENTER);
            
            


        } catch(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/login.csv" , numLinesToSkip = 1)
    void loginlogout(String userid,String password) throws Exception {
        
        //Set FxRobotContext
        robot=new FxRobot();
        loginPage=new LoginPage(robot);
        
        //Load Login screen
        
        loginPage.loadLoginScene(robot,applicationPrimaryStage);
        
        //Enter userid and password
        loginPage.setUserId(robot,userid);
        
        homePage=loginPage.setPassword(robot, password);
    
        
        //Logout Regclient
        result =loginPage.logout(robot);
        
        assertTrue("TestCase Failed",result);
        //return result;
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LoginLogoutTest loginLogoutTest=new LoginLogoutTest();
        
        Application.launch(LoginLogoutTest.class, args); //TILL HERE WORKING FINE

        loginLogoutTest.loginlogout("1111","6666"); // NEED TO REACH HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: I read about Platform.runLater, Worker,Task,Event - Not Sure how to use it.. Any help here.

Comment: This is expected behavior. From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...)): *"The launch method does not return until the application has exited"*. Can't you just put that call in the `start()` method?

Comment: In the start without the testcase call, application launches quickly. And when I call testcase within start method last line, application keeps on loading for around 60sec.. and my testcase throws nullpointer looks like testcase runs and stage is not ready delay...

Comment: @James_D Is there a way, robot get the control of the stage once its shown.. I had tried below code not sure whether this is correct way.. I am unable to reach to testcase call.

Comment: robot=new FxRobot();
   LoginLogoutTest loginLogoutTest=new LoginLogoutTest();
   primaryStage.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
     try {
      System.out.println("In try ");
      loginLogoutTest.loginlogout("110123","mosip123");
     } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED- Using thread able to achieve this..

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException { //1

```
    LoginLogoutTest lg=new LoginLogoutTest();  
    
    Thread thread4 = new Thread() { //3 parallel running
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("thread4 inside calling testcase"); 
                Thread.sleep(120000); //Needed
                robot=new FxRobot();
                LoginLogoutTest lg=new LoginLogoutTest();
                
                lg.loginlogout("110123", "mosip123");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

    };
    
    thread4.start();
    Application.launch(StartApplication.class, args);//2 infine loop never yeild

}   }
```

Comment: Why do you still initialize robot outside of the thread? As far as I can see that's useless.

Comment: Yes thanks for correcting copy paste mistake.

Comment: Updated the solution.